# Spring Long Polling with DeferredResult

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, long-polling

I have a Spring MVC 3.2 application and i need to add a Long Polling to this Web service for a real time chat.
I followed this article [Spring MVC 3.2 Preview: Chat Sample](http://spring.io/blog/2012/05/16/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-chat-sample/).

TopicRestController:

```
 private final Map<DeferredResult<String>, Long> chatRequests =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<DeferredResult<String>, Long>();

 @RequestMapping(value="/{topicId}/updates" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody DeferredResult<String> isNewTopic(
        @PathVariable Long topicId,
        Model model, HttpSession session,
        @RequestParam(required = true) String data) throws InterruptedException, CircularDefinitionException{
    logger.info("New long polling request "+topicId);
    final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<String>();
    this.chatRequests.put(result, topicId);

    result.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chatRequests.remove(result);
            logger.info("Remove request from queue!");
        }
      });

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(Long.valueOf(data)*1000L);
        String updates = talkService.findNewTopicResponce(topicId,timestamp);
        if (!updates.isEmpty()) {
            result.setResult(updates);
        }

    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/{categoryId}" + "/addAnswer", method=POST) 
public @ResponseBody Map respTopic(
        @PathVariable Long categoryId,
        @RequestParam String msg,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String imageUrl,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam long talkId,
        HttpServletRequest request
        ) throws CircularDefinitionException, MessagingException,TalkNotExistException{
     ........................
    for (Entry<DeferredResult<String>, Long> entry :  this.chatRequests.entrySet()){
                            if(entry.getValue().equals(talkId)){        
                                entry.getKey().setResult(""+talkId);
                            }
                        }

    }
```

Now the problem is:

when i call "/{topicId}/updates" if there is not any answer after 30 second the server return Error 500, if someone wrote a message the server return the correct message but the server always responds after 30 seconds, i need the server responds immediately when someone writes a new message and not at the timeout process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and I came across this similar question: [Tomcat 7 server error after 10 seconds when long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571994/tomcat-7-server-error-after-10-seconds-when-long-polling)

Basically, you have to tell Tomcat not to timeout. You do this by editing your `server.xml` Tomcat file (in your `conf` directory) to include an `asyncTimeout` parameter. This would tell your Tomcat to timeout after a minute:

`<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" asyncTimeout="60000" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />`

Using a value of -1 tells Tomcat to never timeout.