# Set timeout for specific async request in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an sync endpoint defined as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/some/url/")
@ResponseBody
public Future<String> something(...) {
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

When the returned `Future` is not completed after 30 seconds the request is cancelled.

How can I increase the timeout for this specific endpoint (e.g. to 100 seconds)?

I only found answers for changing it for all endpoins:

- [Specify timeout for controller async method in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338516/specify-timeout-for-controller-async-method-in-spring)
- [Spring Long Polling with DeferredResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683328/spring-long-polling-with-deferredresult)

Comment: And your problem is....?

Comment: As he already pointed out: the timeout for a specific function only should be increased, not for all endpoints. Would be interested in an answer as well.

Comment: @peq, What is the problem if you increase timeout for all end-point ?

Comment: I am afraid there could be performance problems if I increase it for all endpoints. I guess they had a reason to set the default to 30 seconds.

Comment: Ever found a solution for this? Ps.: Don't understand what's people problem understanding that we know for a fact some specific request will take longer to respond, so we just need to increase timeout for that specific endpoint.

Comment: Our workaround was to use web sockets instead of long polling http requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return [WebAsyncTask](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/WebAsyncTask.html#WebAsyncTask-long-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) that supports timeout.

From docs: [For a Callable, you can use WebAsyncTask to provide a timeout value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-configuration-spring-mvc)

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try to add below property in application.properties.

> spring.mvc.async.request-timeout = # Amount of time (in milliseconds)
>      before asynchronous request handling times out.

Comment: This is off-topic — OP was asking for changing the time that a *specific* request takes...