# Request timeout for endpoint using StreamingResponseBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, timeout

I have a spring MVC endpoint returning `StreamingResponseBody` so I can stream big file instead of keeping it in memory.

The request can take a while to download so it is timing out. I can fix it by setting `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=360000`, but I don't want this setting to apply globally to all endpoints.

Is there way to set request-timeout only for this specific endpoint?

I did find [Set timeout for specific async request in Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025525/set-timeout-for-specific-async-request-in-spring-boot), but I don't think that applies to my code using `StreamingResponseBody`.

I have also found [Spring REST endpoint returning StreamingResponseBody: AsyncRequestTimeoutException after 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030650/spring-rest-endpoint-returning-streamingresponsebody-asyncrequesttimeoutexcepti), which doesn't have the desired effect.

Comment: Show us some code. What annotation did you use on your Controller?

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, this was so long ago I neither remember, nor have access to the code anymore. If you know about annotation that would make this work, then please post an answer.